# Appending any digit in integer value using bitwise operation

Tags: database, bit-manipulation

I want to append any static  single digit in given number using bitwise operation.
Let the static number is 1 ,

```
If the number is
 2  =>  12 
 31 =>  131 
 24 =>  124
 11 =>  111
```

Is it possible to do..?
Here why I am strict with bitwise means , I want to maintain as integer values.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain your restriction better? You can calculate this with integer arithmetic.

Comment: yes, integer arithmetic  also okay....

Comment: @pavun_cool Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If your dbms supports basic math functions (Oracle for instance), you can use:

```
SELECT NUMBER + Power(10, Floor(Log(10, NUMBER)) + 1)
FROM TABLE;
```

If not you could get away with a string trick like:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('1' || TO_CHAR(NUMBER))
FROM TABLE;
```

(using Oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operators won't work that well on *decimal* numbers since powers of two and powers of ten don't mesh well (I have *no* idea what the database tag is for here, this seems to be totally unrelated).

If you want a function to add a 1 to the left of an arbitrary number as you seem to indicate, you can use the following algorithm:

```
def prefixWithOne (n):
    if n == 0:
        return 10
    addNum = 1
    testNum = n
    while testNum > 0:
        testNum = int (testNum / 10)
        addNum = addNum * 10
    return addNum + n
```

For example, the following C code will do that:

```
unsigned int prefixWithOne (unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int testNum = n;
    unsigned int addNum = 1;
    if (n == 0) return 10;
    while (testNum > 0) {
        testNum /= 10;
        addNum *= 10;
    }
    return addNum + n;
}
```

(with the usual caveats about watching out for overflow).